# Disable auto trigger of Azure Devops release using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-releases

I'm currently working on an "if condition" azure data factory pipeline which will be part of **Release 1**. My use case is to count the total row of two table. If the row count for both table is same, proceed with other Azure devops **Release 2** activity (refer pic below). If the row is unmatch it will send notification email and disable auto trigger on azure devops **Release 2**.

**My Question is, How can I disable auto trigger of release two from ADF pipeline**.

My Azure Data Factory and Azure Devops release design as below;

[image: My ADF pipeline design]

[image: My Azure Devops with auto trigger between release 1 and release 2]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using azure data factory, I write a python script and compare between two tables and run in the Azure Devops pipeline.